# How to fix sound clipping and cluttering when playing successive wave sounds using naudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I'm using Naudio and trying to generate a code which takes a list of notes(including semitones or quarter tones) and play it by playing individual notes from corresponding wave files.
I can hear Sound clipping at end of each wave file played

the code i made is working but i found out that there is clipping of the sound at the end of each note played. any recommendations how to solve this?? any recommendations about using a circular buffer to buffer the waves into then playing them? is there anyway that i can start with to understand and use circular buffers with naudio?

in the following code.. seeka.ladder is a list of 8 notes that is sent to player to be played. eatch note is taking and the corresponding wave is played after it is pitch shifted according to its accidental (semitones or quarter tones)

i will provide the full code if needed.

```
   class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {


    var seeka = new Maqam(new Note()
     { Type = NoteType.E,Accedintal=AccedintalType.HBmol }, new int[] { 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3 }, new int[] { 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2 });

            var player = new NotePlayer();
            var path = @"C:\Users\ahmad\source\repos\OudPlayBack\OudPlayBack\Resources\"
                            + note.Type.ToString().ToLower()+ note.Octave +".wav";
            player.play(seeka.ForewardLadder);


        }

    }

    public class NotePlayer
        {

        private double upOneQuartertone;
        private double downOneQuartertone;
        private double upOneSemitone;
        private double downOneSemitone;
        public NotePlayer()
        {
            upOneQuartertone = Math.Pow(2, 1.0 / 24);
            downOneQuartertone = 1.0 / upOneQuartertone;
            upOneSemitone = upOneQuartertone * upOneQuartertone;
            downOneSemitone = 1 / upOneSemitone;
        }

        public void Play(Note note, string notePath)
        {
            var factor = SetFactor(note);

            using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(notePath))
            {
                var pitch = new SmbPitchShiftingSampleProvider(reader.ToSampleProvider());
                using (var device = new WaveOutEvent())
                {

                    pitch.PitchFactor = (float)factor; // or downOneTone
                                                        // just playing the first 10 seconds of the file
                    device.Init(pitch.Take(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
                    device.Volume = 1;
                    device.Play();
                    var x = 0;
                    while (device.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(5);
                        x += 5;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine(x);

                }

            }
        }

        public void play(List<Note> score)
        {
            foreach (var tempnote in score)
            {
                tempnote.Octave += 1;
                var ipath = @"C:\Users\ahmad\source\repos\OudPlayBack\OudPlayBack\Resources\"
                            + tempnote.Type.ToString().ToLower() + tempnote.Octave + ".wav";
                this.Play(tempnote, ipath);
            }
        }
        private double SetFactor(Note note)
        {
            double factor = 1.0;
            switch (note.Accedintal)
            {
                case AccedintalType.Bmol:
                    factor = downOneSemitone;
                    break;
                case AccedintalType.HBmol:
                    factor = downOneQuartertone;
                    break;
                case AccedintalType.Natural:

                    break;
                case AccedintalType.HDiaz:
                    factor = upOneQuartertone;
                    break;
                case AccedintalType.Diaz:
                    factor = upOneSemitone;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return factor;
        }
    }
```

the program works well and plays the notes but there is obvious clipping and cluttering at the sound.. it becomes so obvious at the end of each note.. is it because of disposing the player ? and starting a new one? how to solve this?? is there any better way to do this with soundfonts or any library other than Naudio?